# Expressão regular em pattern

Tags: html5, regex

Tenho um input do tipo texto que estou validando com expressão regular, a regra da expressão é a seguinte: começa com um número entre 0 e 2 e depois mais 6 números aleatórios, mas não sei qual o motivo do não funcionamento dela.

```
<input pattern="^[0-2][0-9]{6}$" required type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

Segue todo o código da página..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Lista de Serviços</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Selecione o setor <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">APS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GEX</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logística</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seat</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px;min-width: 250px;">
                    <li>
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                             <form class="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <input pattern="^[0-2][0-9]{6}$" required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Matrícula" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                                </div>
                             </form>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
             </ul>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Para mim funciona... https://jsfiddle.net/aLrff0j2/ qual é o problema que estás a ter?

Comment: quando digito por exemplo 2155898 ele mostra mensagem de erro, mesmo estando no padrão.

Comment: Na verdade, quando testei seu exemplo, também funcionou... https://jsfiddle.net/aLrff0j2/1/

Comment: @user37750 Que browser estás a usar?

Comment: Estou usando o Google Chrome.

Comment: Acabei de testar no mozila e da o mesmo erro

Comment: Você já tentou criar uma página separada, apenas com esse input, para verficar este erro?

Comment: Tentei em uma página separada e funcionou, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Então já sabemos que o problema está em meio ao seu código, não imagino o que seja, mas você poderia postá-lo, apenas o que você acha que pode estar causando isso, assim poderemos analisá-lo.

Comment: postei todo o código da página

Comment: Só uma dúvida, o erro a que você se refere é o fator de não poder submeter o form mesmo com números válidos?

Comment: sim é esse erro

Comment: Copiei o seu código, e linkei o bootstrap, e o form de login funciona normalmente...Olhe: http://s12.postimg.org/e52avc8dp/Captura_de_Tela_12.png

Comment: Pra mim aqui também funcionou

Comment: Sua resposta para a pergunta do Samir Braga mostra que você não adicionou o method "POST" na tag form.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir o primeiro digito como abaixo:

```
pattern="^[0-2]{1}[0-9]{6}$"
```